# No video output from MiniDP laptop to DVI monitor via mDP hub

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dvi, thinkpad

My Lenovo Thinkpad S430 has two ports: miniHDMI and miniDisplayPort/Thunderbolt

Now I purchased a miniDisplayPort hub 1-3 input is miniDP and output is HDMI, DisplayPort and DVI.

My external monitor has DVI connection so i plugin my DVI cable to monitor and then to hub and then miniDP cable to my pc. I checked BIOS i have Nvidia selected and I have DP port enabled.

However when I connect the thing nothing happens I get not output at all. Im running Windows 7 do i required some additional divers or am i missing something else ?

Specs:
Windows 7 Home
GPU: (3rd Gen) Intel HD 4000 with Nvidia 620M Optimus
CPU: i5 2.5 GHZ DualCore
RAM: 4GB

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to switch display modes, try making sure it's set at "duplicate" so your image is being sent both to the screen and your external monitor. If this doesn't work, it sounds like it might be the adapter. If you right click your desktop and choose "Screen resolution", it should show you all screens currently connected. If you only have one, that means your external monitor isn't even being detected, which is likely to be caused by some compability issue with cables or adapters.

As an anecdote, I once had an issue getting an image from a Thinkpad with one HDMI cable that worked with another computer, nothing seemed to work until I tried another cable. Must have been different types in some way, but I guess what I'm trying to point out is that it's always good to try out other cables to make sure it's not a hardware problem before spending hours and hours troubleshooting drivers and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try:

- Tried pressing Windows Key + P (to switch monitor to an external monitor)?
- Or check if the monitor is even detected by right clicking on  your desktop, and choose "Screen Resolution" and see if your external monitor is displayed or not (and try pressing "Detect")
- Is your monitor on? Do you get the message any message from the monitor?
- Checked with Lenovo Support? Maybe they don't support using the hub you have, and need it to use their [product](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/itemdetails/0B47090/460/8FA0422CA6EA48B0BDED71D287F73673)
- Is the hub working? (any other PC/Mac to test it with?)

Hope this helps.